# Not Getting Partition Elimination on a Foreign Key Join in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, partitioning

I have a rather large fact table in SQL Server that is partitioned by a foreign key to a date dimension. The foreign key constraint is both enabled and trusted. When I add something like this to the where clause:

```
 "F_ClinicInvoiceTransaction".ServiceDateKey>=40908 and "F_ClinicInvoiceTransaction".ServiceDateKey<42247
```

I get partition elimination. However when I simply join on the ServiceDateKey and filter on a date range as such:

```
  "D_Calendar"."CalendarKey" ="F_ClinicInvoiceTransaction"."ServiceDateKey"
   AND "D_Calendar".StartDT>='2012-01-01'  and "D_Calendar".StartDT<'2015-10-01'
```

The partition elimination goes away. Is there a way to get partition elimination based on this join or am I stuck filtering explicitly on values in the fact table?

Comment: What is your table partitioned on? What are the plans? Data model? All joins/where predicates?

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen ServiceDateKey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really is much easier to answer these questions when you give more details -- but I will try and answer as best I can:

1. Perform a sub-query with your 2nd filter ("D_Calendar".StartDT>='2012-01-01'  and "D_Calendar".StartDT<'2015-10-01' ) and just get Min and Max values of ServiceDateKey.
2. Use the min and max values of ServiceDateKey to perform your full query, now that it has min and max values it can do partition elimination.  Using those values in the where clause like your first query does.

While it seems like doing these two steps will be slower it is often the case that the partition elimination will give faster results.  Esp. with big data sets.

Comment: The join to the subquery for this did get me my parition elimination. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot gain partition elimination by filtering on another column in another table. It needs to be on the actual partitioned column in the table and needs to be filered in the where clause. Found the answer here: [https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21770](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21770/partition-key-questions-in-sql-server-2008/24847)

Comment: Please see my answer for a way to solve this problem.